# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato de un campo date que está en un controlador y no en el modelo?

Tags: python, web2py

Tengo una data que es así:

```
db.define_table('registro',
                Field('numero_documento', 'string'),
                Field('usuario', 'reference usuarios'),
                Field('fecha_ingreso', 'date'),
                format='%(numero_documento)s'
                )
```

El formato por defecto es dia/mes/año y si quisiera cambiarlo solo tendría que añadirle esto al final de mi modelo:

```
db.registro.fecha_ingreso.represent = lambda value, row: value.strftime('%y/%m/%d)
```

Ahora, la duda que tengo es cómo puedo hacer este mismo proceso en un controlador el cual es este:

```
def datos_fechas():
    form = SQLFORM.factory(
        Field('usuario', 'reference usuarios',requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.usuarios, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----')),
        Field('desde', 'date'),
        Field('hasta', 'date'),
    )
    data = db((db.registro.usuario==usuario) &
                  ((db.registro.fecha_ingreso>=desde) & (db.registro.fecha_ingreso<=hasta))
                  ).select(
            db.usuarios.nombre,
            db.registro.numero_documento,
            db.registro.fecha_ingreso,
            left=(
                db.usuarios.on(db.usuarios.id==db.registro.usuario),
            )
    )
```

Los campos `inicio` y `final` tienen el formato `d/m/y` y quiero cambiarlo al formato `y/m/d`.

Comment: ¿Te refieres al formato del formulario?

Comment: claro, quiero que tenga un formato especifico.

Comment: @Elenasys que pena! 296 días es bastante tiempo =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te refieres al formulario, es posible pasarle un validador para forzar el formato usando `IS_DATE`:

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(
    Field('usuario', 'reference usuarios',requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.usuarios, '%(nombre)s', zero='---- Elegir Opcion ----')),
    Field('desde', 'date', requires=IS_DATE(format='%y-%m-%d')),
    Field('hasta', 'date', requires=IS_DATE(format='%y-%m-%d')),
)
```

Para más información puedes ver la sección [Forms and Validators](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators).